# U shaped poly-lines giving a trouble in selecting other poly-lines in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

I have `QGraphicsView` which contains many rectangles and polylines. My view looks something like this.
[image]

If I click on position A , B, C , D orange color polyline gets selected. If I try to select polyline inside U - shaped orange polyline, they never get selected. Only the orange color polyline gets selected.

If I click on position E, F, G a blue color polyline gets selected. I can not select anything which is inside of these U - shaped polylines. If I try to select anything inside these U - shaped polylines, only U shaped polyline gets selected.

There are many polylines and rectangles in the design. But this problem arises with only U - shaped polylines. Other polylines ( which are not U shape, and which are not inside U - shaped polylines get selected properly. )

There is a by default Qt's selection method of any QGraphicsItem. If you click on them, it creates a dotted rectangle around that item. So, in U shape polylines, it also creates a dotted rectangle and if you click inside that rectangle, only that polyline gets selected.
In paint() method I have changed that default selection method of Qt, but I think there is still a problem which is not letting me to select other polylines.

```
void myPoly::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                             QWidget *widget)
{
    auto copied_option = *option;
    copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
    auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
    QGraphicsPathItem::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
    if (selected) {
        painter->save();
        painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
        painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::SolidLine));
        painter->drawPath(shape());
        painter->restore();
    }
}
```

> I tried with setBoundingRegionGranularity(1) but it did not work.

Selection of  QGraphicsItem through paint() is incomplete ? Or this problem is not related to paint() but related to some other problem like placing of polylines ?

Comment: @G.M.  Can you look into this problem ?

Comment: @m7913d  Soheil Armin Can you look into this problem ?